# How can I prevent a "pimple hole" from scarring?

Tags: dermatology, prevention, acne

I had a whitehead building on my nose for weeks, and I decided enough was enough and squeezed it out. It didn't pop, it just kind of came out. But it left a hole, like an actual open hole, about a millimeter in diamater. How do I prevent that from turning into a scar?